# Deleting a picture with Ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have a system where I can upload pictures from different users. Each user can then access a tab where he can see all the pictures that he uploaded by himself. From this tab the user should also be able to click on a button and delete each one induvidually.

I am struggling to make this work so I hope that somebody can help me out.

This is what my database looks like:

- table: pictures, rows:

  - descPicture
  - id
  - imageFullNamePicture
  - titlePicture
  - userid
- table: users, rows:

  - user_email
  - user_id
  - user_name
  - user_password
  - user_phone
  - user_zip

This is my code:

DBH.INC.PHP

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "chhoe17";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",
    $username,
    $password,
    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));


}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

UPLOAD.PHP

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';
include_once "includes/dbh.inc.php";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="main-container">
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <h2>Manage your pictures</h2>

            <?php
            //display a message and images if logged in!
            if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
              echo "Upload your pictures";

              echo '<div class="picture-upload">
            <h2>Upload</h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <form action="upload.inc.php" id="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="text" name="filetitle" placeholder="Image title">
              <input type="text" name="filedesc" placeholder="Image description">
              <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
              <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>




          </div>';
            }

            if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
              echo ' <section class="picture-links">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>Pictures</h2> ';

              ?>

            <div id="pictures">
                <?php



                $sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE userid = '{$_SESSION['u_id']}'";

                //$sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 20;";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $pictures = $stmt->fetchAll();

                // if ($pictures !== null) {
                foreach ($pictures as $pic) {
                  ?>
                <li>
                    <figure id="<?php echo $pic['id']; ?>">
                        <b>
                            <figcaption><?php echo $pic["titlePicture"] ?>
                                <img src=<?php echo $pic["imageFullNamePicture"]  ?>>
                                <?php echo $pic["descPicture"] ?> <br>
                    </figure>
                </li>


                <span><input type="submit" id="del_btn" value="Delete Image" /></span>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("input#del_btn").click(function() {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "delete.php", // 
                                data: {
                                    id: <?php echo $delid; ?>
                                },
                                success: function(msg) {
                                    alert("Your picture has been deleted");
                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    alert("failure");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>



                <?php

              }

            }
            ?>



            </div>



        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>

<?php
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

DELETE.PHP

```
<?php
include_once "includes/dbh.inc.php";

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $picID = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM pictures WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($picID));
}

?>
```

As it is right now, nothing happens when I click the delete buttons that are attached to the pictures, and I dont get any alerts either. Any help that somebody could provide to make this work, would be very appreciated.

Comment: there is a mass of code there and it's quite hard to decipher what is what but by the looks of things you are repeating sections of HTML in a loop - these repeated sections of html include duplicated IDs which is not valid. The javascript is listening for one such ID but it also appears that the event listener code is also in the loop??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-using `id` values, so when your jQuery selector executes which element should it find?  Additionally, you're repeating the client-side click handler over and over in your loop.  This can all be simplified.

Use a `class` to identify your "delete" button, and put the relevant `id` in a data attribute:

```
<button type="button" class="del_btn" data-id="<?php echo $delid; ?>">Delete Image</button>
```

Then later, *outside the loop*, create a single event handler which will listen on all the buttons and use the button's `data-id` to make the AJAX request:

```
$('input.del_btn').on('click', function() {
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    $.post('delete.php', { id: id })
     .done(function () {
         alert('Your picture has been deleted');
     })
     .fail(function () {
         alert('failure');
     });
});
```